# Prove the limit problems

Tags: real-analysis

I got two problems asking for the proof of the limit:

> Prove the following limit: 
> $$\sup_{x\ge 0}\ x e^{x^2}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2} \, dt={1\over 2}.$$

and,

> Prove the following limit: 
> $$\sup_{x\gt 0}\ x\int_0^\infty {e^{-px}\over {p+1}} \, dp=1.$$

I may feel that these two problems are of the same kind. World anyone please help me with one of them and I may figure out the other one? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$ f(x)=\ x e^{x^2}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2} \implies f(x)=\ x e^{x^2}g(x).$$

We can see that $ f(0)=0 $ and $f(x)>0,\,\, \forall x>0$. Taking the limit as $x$ goes to infinity and using L'hobital's rule and Leibniz integral rule yields

$$ \lim_{ x\to \infty } xe^{x^2}g(x) = \lim _{x\to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{\frac{1}{xe^{x^2}}}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g'(x)}{\frac{1}{(xe^{x^2})'}}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-e^{-x^2}}{{-{\frac {{{\rm e}^{-{x}^{2}}} \left( 2\,{x}^{2}+1 \right) }{{x}^{2}}}}} =\frac{1}{2}. $$

Comment: This was my initial answer but it wasn't upvoted. I'm glad to see it here (+1)

Comment: The problem asks for $\sup$. If you can show the function is monotonic increasing, then you have the $\sup$ is $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

After a suitable substitution, both limits are easily handled by [Dominated Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) or [Monotone Convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem).

---

**The First Integral**

Substituting $t\mapsto\sqrt{t+x^2}$,
$$
\begin{align}
xe^{x^2}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=xe^{x^2}\int_0^\infty e^{-t-x^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{2\sqrt{t+x^2}}\\
&=\frac12\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1+t/x^2}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Equation $(1)$ shows that the integrand is increasing with $x$ and by Dominated or Monotone Convergence, the limit is
$$
\frac12\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac12\tag{2}
$$

---

**The Second Integral**

Substituting $p\mapsto p/x$,
$$
\begin{align}
x\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-px}}{p+1}\,\mathrm{d}p
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-p}}{1+p/x}\,\mathrm{d}p\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Equation $(3)$ shows that the integrand is increasing with $x$ and by Dominated or Monotone Convergence, the limit is
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-p}\,\mathrm{d}p=1\tag{4}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, use integration by parts, followed by crude estimation.

Let $u=\frac{1}{t}$ and $dv=te^{-t^2}\,dt$. Then $du=-\frac{1}{t^2}\,dt$ and we can take $v=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-t^2}$. Thus our integral is equal to
$$\frac{1}{x}\cdot \frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}-\int_x^\infty \frac{1}{2t^2}e^{-t^2}\,dt.$$
Multiplying $\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}$ by $xe^{x^2}$ gives us the main term. It remains to check that $\int_x^\infty \frac{1}{2t^2}e^{-t^2}\,dt$ is  small enough that multiplying by $xe^{x^2}$ gives a small result.

We have 
$$\int_x^\infty \frac{1}{2t^2}e^{-t^2}\,dt \lt \frac{1}{2x^2}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt.$$ 
We can bound $\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt$ by integrating from $x$ to $x+1$, and from $x+1$ to $\infty$. The integral from $x$ to $x+1$ is $\lt e^{-x^2}$.

For $x+1$ to $\infty$, make the change of variable $t=s+1$. We want
$\int_{s=x}^\infty e^{-s^2-2s-1}\,ds$, which is less than $e^{-x^2}\int_x^\infty e^{-2s-1}\,ds$.  The remaining integral is bounded by a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do the second one. And it appears that André Nicolas did the first one while I was writing, so everything is fine.

By integration by parts, 
$$
x\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-px}}{p+1}dp=1-\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-px}}{(p+1)^2}dp\leq 1
$$
for all $x>0$.

Now by Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, the rhs tends to $1-0=1$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$.

So the sup over $x>0$ is indeed $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The main things I'd add to the other answers is to explicitly apply the definition of a limit, rather than leave it all to higher-level theorems, since the OP said the problem was proving the *limits*.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = L \Leftrightarrow \forall \; \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists \; N > 0 \ni x > N \Rightarrow \left| f(x) - L \right| < \varepsilon$$

$$\;\\ x e^{x^2}\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2} \, dt = \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} x e^{x^2}\int_x^b e^{-t^2} \, dt = L \Leftrightarrow \\ \forall \; \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists \; N > 0 \ni b > N \Rightarrow \left| e^{x^2}\int_x^b e^{-t^2} \, dt - L \right| < \varepsilon$$

$$\;\\ \text{Let} L = {1\over2}$$

$$\text{Show:} \; \forall \; \varepsilon > 0 \; \exists \; N > 0 \ni b > N \Rightarrow \left| x e^{x^2}\int_x^b e^{-t^2} \, dt - {1\over2} \right| < \varepsilon$$

And the rest of the whole rigmarole of finding some expression for $N$ containing $\varepsilon$ and $x$ that you can prove is always big enough (and then doing so).